# How to add files containing '@' character to depot using P4V

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v, wechat

I have an issue with P4V where I need to add a third party library (WeChat specifically) to source control and it has files in it containing '@' in the file name. P4V seems to URL encode these characters meaning that it cannot find the files when it tries to commit the change. I've been reading around and apparently there is a way to 'force-add' files with perforce but I can't figure out how to do this in P4V.

Unfortunately the simple option of just renaming the files isn't available to me.

Comment: Well, you only have to **add** the files once, so why not use the command line for the add? Run `p4 add -f file@sign.txt` to get the file marked for add, then submit it, and from then on P4V will be able to work with it. If you have a set of such files, use a wildcard pattern in your `p4 add -f`.

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it seemed to work, however it seems I actually have a different issue the filename seems to be ',png' instead of '.png' in the error. I think this is the correct answer for this particular problem, I'll submit a new question for the new problem.

Comment: Okay I found the actual issue - it seems to be to do with the path length exceeding a certain limit. Looks to be about 200 characters. I'm going to try creating a workspace with a shorter name mapped to a directory closer to the files I want to add.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an old folder, have you tried using "Diff Against" between the old folder and the current folder containing those files?

You could simply use the "Mark for Add" function by right-clicking the folder/s.
I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: This is what I'm doing and it doesn't work because it has the @ sign in the file name.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong about @ being the problem - see my comments above.